# Are non-competing answers allowed?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-question

What prompted this question was a unique case, but I feel that it is generally applicable.

## Are non-competing answers allowed on this site?

A non-competing answer is one which is not taken into contention when determining the best/smallest/fastest answer to a question/challenge. Obviously there have been cases where partially finished answers have been posted and updated, answers have been found not to work or otherwise been disqualified, etc..

But is a user, at the time of posting an answer, allowed to intend it not to compete? For example, if someone wanted to give an answer in a language which cannot be run / executed in practice, or the designer of a language such as Pyth / GolfScript wanted to show a new feature to be included in an upcoming release, would these be accepted *provided that the users make it obvious they are non-competing answers*?

If so, how should answers be marked as non-competing?

### Specific case:

I'm building a language, QBF, which is *not* specifically designed for code-golf. The grammar has been almost static for three years at this point, and I am beginning to look into how it will be formally defined and implemented. So while what it looks like is known, what the base language will have is still under consideration.

Needless to say, it does not come close to meeting the criteria to be used in a competing answer.

However, I do believe that it would help me to make better design choices, have an existing unit-test archive, and generate questions from other people about issues I wouldn't consider on my own. It may even generate some limited interest in the project, or inform me that the entire thing is a train-wreck and I should start over.

Comment: Quoting from the linked thread: *Marking an answer as **non-competing** does not exempt it from being invalid.* The only exception to this rule is using a programming language (or a feature thereof) that was implemented after the challenge was posted.

Comment: @Dennis That's a bit disappointing, but makes sense.

Comment: Have you considered [chat]?

Comment: @trichoplax Actually I hadn't, that could work well in conjunction with some archival system for the solutions... Thanks for the idea.

Comment: I meant as a place to chat about language features rather than a place to post solutions - there are quite a few people interested in language design chatting there.